# Done building project "Project.vcxproj" -- FAILED

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I wrote some lines of code to simply read and write an image and it was working a few days ago, but now Visual Studio gives these errors: "1>Done building project "Lab1_PI.vcxproj" -- FAILED." and it says it was "unable to start the program" and that the system cannot find the file specified.

I also tried to add add _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE and _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS via right-click project->C/C+±>Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions, but nothing changed.

Also, here's my code, but it is correct since it was working a few days ago:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int arc, const char** argv) {
   string imgPath = argv[1];
   string img2Path = argv[2];

   cv::Mat  img = imread(imgPath);

   if (!img.data) {
       cout << "error:no image" << endl;
       return -1;
   }

   imshow("flower image (color)", img);

   Mat img2;
   cvtColor(img, img2, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

   imwrite(img2Path, img2);

   imshow("flower image (grey)", img2);

   waitKey(0);

}
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me fix this problem because it stops me from using Visual Studio and I really need it for a project!

Comment: And there is no other error? What does the output say before that line?

Comment: What are the other errors before that?

Comment: @PMF this is what I get: Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Lab1_PI, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Lab2_PI.obj : error LNK2005: main already defined in Lab1_PI.obj
1>C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\Lab1_PI\x64\Debug\Lab1_PI.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "Lab1_PI.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: There's your error: `error LNK2005: main already defined in Lab1_PI.obj`. You have multiple "main" methods. Apparently because you include both Lab1_Pl.cpp and Lab2_Pl.cpp in the build. Choose either.